# nginx.conf and nginx.pid users and permissions

Tags: nginx, server, pid

I'm embarking on watching my NGINX error.log files at level: warn... probably a silly idea and will cause me to crash my server as I work out any bugs happening, but hey, we're nerds and this is why we're here.

I'm noticing a [warn] and an [emerg] pop up every time I restart my server, which shows:

```
[warn] 8041#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
[emerg] 8041#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

The top of my nginx.conf file reads:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

Which to me, shows me a few things.

1. I'm running NGINX with the user: www-data.
2. The number of worker processes that are allowed is automatically adjusted.
3. my PID file/information is being stored in /run/nginx.pid.

The error tells me that NGINX doesn't have permission to access /run/nginx.pid, which led me to see the user permissions for said file.

```
sudo ls -la /run/nginx.pid
```

reveals:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Jun 18 05:34 /run/nginx.pid
```

Then trying:

```
ps -ef | grep nginx
```

produces:

```
root      5914     1  0 05:34 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /u
www-data  5917  5914  0 05:34 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

*scratches head*

Now, can somebody out there tell me why, or how the hell NGINX has managed to create the master process with root ownership, and now the worker processes are owned by www-data?

Or more to the point, anybody have some suggestions on what to do about this [emerg] error I'm getting?

My first thought is to just try and change the ownership of the /run/nginx.pid file and see how NGINX likes it, but I kind of feel that even if I do that manually this time, when I restart the server, I'll run into the same problem.

My second thought is maybe there is somewhere else that I define my worker process initiation within NGINX..

Thanks.

***EDIT***

The contents of the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service` file are:

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/nginx -s quit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: That is the correct behaviour of the `user` parameter ([see this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user)).  The error also stems from from the fact that `nginx` is designed to run the master process as `root`.  How are you starting `nginx`?  `systemd?` `init-v`?  Is the binary `setuid` by any chance?

Comment: OK. So NGINX is supposed to run the master process as root. So everything is as it should be with regards to permissions as shown above. I still am befuddled why my [emerg] error pops up. My NGINX starts with the AWS server, that hardly ever down. However, if I do restart using `sudo service nginx restart` I see the above mentioned error. Can you show me how to find exactly how it's starting so I can answer your question @grochmal?

Comment: Well, different OSes currently have different start procedures, although `systemd` is by far the most common.  If you have the `systemctl` command you're using `systemd`, and if you have it the file that will explain to us how `nginx` starts shall be under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service`.

Comment: Please see the EDIT I've added to the question above. I think this means that it's systemd, @grochmal, ? I also see that the `nginx.pid` declarations are matching in both my `nginx.conf` file and my `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service` file, and that it's forking. So nothing alerts me yet, perhaps I'm not seeing it?

Comment: That explains why the master process runs as `root` right?  (systemd has no directive in `ExecStart=` to run as another user).  Now, your worker process is running as `ww-data` therefore `nginx` is not ignoring `user www-data;`.  Therefore the errors are baffling.  In which log do you see these errors? Inside `error_log` as configured in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: This is correct, @grochmal, I have set a global error_log file for all of my virtual servers as `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;` inside of my html {} block.

Comment: Ever found a way out of this? Having the exact same two errors/warning, and this post is the best search result I can find so far.

Comment: Nothing yet really, @AlexTimmer

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error on my Centos 7 server today.

> nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

For me, it turned out to be a problem with SELinux. I did the following to make it work again:

```
systemctl stop nginx
touch /var/run/nginx.pid
chcon -u system_u -t httpd_var_run_t /var/run/nginx.pid
systemctl start nginx
```

running

```
ls -Z nginx.pid
```

should output

> -rw-r--r--. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 nginx.pid

Comment: what directory are you running that from? your third line references `nginx.pid` as relative, but apparently there's a `/run/nginx.pid` and a `/var/run/nginx.pid`.

Comment: +1 for this, it solved my issue on CentOS 7. The issue happened due a previous installation that was in a much lower version that I needed, which was installed 1.12 and I needed 1.17. Running the touch command without being in the folder the nginx.pid was not being created though, I had to go directly in the folder for it to take propper effect.

Comment: This worked on centos 8 with nginx 1.19 after running third command from directory /var/run/

Comment: Worked for me too! Edited to add the path in the chcon.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got a

```
    "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

    bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

and the working solution was made up of these steps:

1. stop root process

   ```
   sudo nginx -s stop
   ```
2. check if process stopped

   ```
   ps aux | grep nginx
   ```
3. restart process

   ```
   sudo nginx -s reload
   ```

gave me the error

```
    nginx: [error] open() “/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid” failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

probabil .pid was started with the wrong root user as I uncommented the line with path to .pid in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf and then I commented it back again

4. to start nginx as a user and not root

   ```
   brew services start nginx
   ```
5. result at running command

   ```
   ps aux | grep nginx

   youruser 89212 0.0 0.0 4268280 644 s002  S+ 2:46PM 0:00.00 grep nginx
   youruser 89179 0.0 0.0 4302204 1776 ?? S 2:45PM 0:00.00 nginx: worker process  
   youruser 89178 0.0 0.0  4275372 4368 ?? S 2:45PM 0:00.01 nginx: master process /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off;
   ```

And as it can be seen, the nginx process started with the expected user and not as root and the conflict between processes was gone and I could access the PHP application local domain.

Answer (score 1):

###### For Ubuntu 20.04+

I got the exact same error while I was using `sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Using **`sudo service nginx restart`** instead throws no error