# Nginx.pid Permission Denied

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx through brew and it appears to be configured and working correctly - to a point.  I have multiple host files (around 20 sites) and almost all of them work fine, however, any new sites added will not work.

All old host files seem to load just fine, for example with server name `site.test` on port 80, but any new host files added return with a "Server not found" in my web browsers.

After much troubleshooting and Google searching, I've finally found something that seems odd in my setup and it was this post that triggered it:  [nginx.conf and nginx.pid users and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894060/nginx-conf-and-nginx-pid-users-and-permissions).  Although it doesn't seem to solve my exact problem.

When I run `nginx -t` I get:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

However, when I run `sudo nginx -t` I get:

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I have both killed nginx and stopped it gracefully with brew and restarted it with sudo, but I appear to get the same issue with nginx.pid.

When I start nginx, I use:  `sudo brew services start nginx`

Running `ps aux | grep nginx`, returns:

```
Media32           7444   0.0  0.0  4339424   2016   ??  S    12:16pm   0:00.01 nginx: worker process  
Media32           7443   0.0  0.0  4339424   1836   ??  S    12:16pm   0:00.00 nginx: worker process  
root              7440   0.0  0.0  4297440   4876   ??  Ss   12:16pm   0:00.01 nginx: master process /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off;
```

Which should be correct as my user is setup in nginx.conf to be `user Media32 staff`.

I can provide any other code necessary, but I have been at a bit of a loss for days on this now and any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I appear to have solved this by editing `/etc/hosts` and adding a record for the new host files, ie. `127.0.0.1 site.test` and then after reloading nginx it worked, but I have never had to do this before, can anyone shed any light on why this is needed and wasn't needed prior?

Comment: It should not be related to your update I think. It's how your computer resolves the hosts. It's only important to point your nginx server at 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this issue in macOS Catalina.

```
sudo brew services stop nginx

sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid

sudo brew services start nginx

nginx -t
```

Comment: Warning: nginx must be run as non-root to start at user login! but i have ignore this and working fine.

Comment: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "kartify.loc" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
bug nginx is working

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that setting any new host in /private/etc/hosts as

```
    127.0.0.1 mysite.test
```

is a rule when adding a new host domain locally,

In my case I got a

```
 the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2

"/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

and the working solution was made up of these steps:

1. stop root process

   ```
   sudo nginx -s stop
   ```
2. check if process stopped

   ```
   ps aux | grep nginx
   ```
3. restart process

   ```
   sudo nginx -s reload
   ```

gave me the error

```
nginx: [error] open() “/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid” failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

probabil .pid was started with the wrong root user as I uncommented the line with path to .pid in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf and then I commented it back again

4. to start nginx as a user and not root

   ```
   brew services start nginx
   ```
5. result at running command

   ```
   ps aux | grep nginx

   youruser 89212 0.0 0.0 4268280 644 s002  S+ 2:46PM 0:00.00 grep nginx
   youruser 89179 0.0 0.0 4302204 1776 ?? S 2:45PM 0:00.00 nginx: worker process  
   youruser 89178 0.0 0.0  4275372 4368 ?? S 2:45PM 0:00.01 nginx: master process /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off;
   ```

And as it can be seen, the nginx process started with the expected user and not as root and the conflict between processes was gone and I could access the PHP application local domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running nginx -t as the root user using "sudo nginx -t" since the configuration checker requires root permissions.

(This solved the problem for me)

Answer (score 0):

here only works stopping the php and running the specific version with brew:

> sudo brew services restart nginx && sudo brew services stop php &&
> sudo brew services restart php@7.4